If $v \in \ell^2$ then is $\sum_j v_j/\sqrt{j}$ absolutely convergent?
I was trying to show that the Hilbert matrix $H(i, j) = (i + j + 1)^{-1}$ where $i, j = 0,1 \dots$ is a bounded operator on $\ell^2$. Using Hilbert inequality, I was able to show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left ( \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{v_j}{i + j + 1} \right )^2 &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{v_i v_j}{(i+k+1)(j+k+1)}  \\
&= \sum_{i} v_i \sum_k \sum_j \frac{v_j}{j+k+1}\cdot \frac{1}{i+k + 1}  \\ 
&\le \sum_{i} v_i \sum_k \sum_j \frac{v_j}{j+k+\frac 1 2 }\cdot \frac{1}{i+k + 1} \\
&\le \sum_i v_i  \pi  \|v\| \sqrt {\sum_k \frac{1}{(i+k+1)^2}} \\
&\le \pi \|v\| \sum_i v_i \sqrt{\sum_k \frac 1 {(i + k+1)^2}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Although I tried a different approach, I would like to know the absolute sum $\sum_i v_i \sqrt{\sum_k \frac 1 {(i + k+1)^2}}\sim \sum_i v_i/\sqrt i $ converge.

Note that $|{v_k \over \sqrt{k}}| \le |v_k|$ for all $k \ne 0$.

For a sequence $a_n$ the series $\sum a_nv_n$ is convergent for every $(v_n)\in \ell^2$ iff $(a_n)\in \ell^2.$ The sequence $a_n=n^{-1/2}$ does not belong to $\ell^2.$

Best practice is to include the question being asked in the post itself, not just in the title. As of now, the title and the post ask somewhat different questions.
The answer to the question in the title is no. An example of a positive $\ell^2$ sequence $\{v_j\}$ such that $\sum_j v_j/\sqrt j$ diverges is $v_j  = 1/(\sqrt j\cdot\log j)$.
